# John Tukey "median median" (or "resistant line") statistical test for R and linear regression

Tags: algorithm, function, r, testing, linear-regression

I'm searching the John Tukey algorithm which compute a "resistant line" or "median-median line" on my linear regression with R.

A student on a mailling list explain this algorithm in these terms :

> "The way it's calculated is to divide
>   the data into three groups, find the
>   x-median and y-median values (called
>   the summary point) for each group, and
>   then use those three summary points to
>   determine the line.  The outer two
>   summary points determine the  slope,
>   and an average of all of them
>   determines the intercept."

Article about John tukey's median median for curious : http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/06/23/tukey-median-ninther/

Do you have an idea of where i could find this algorithm or R function ? In which packages,
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually, the function `line` does exactly that. Or should...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a description of how to calculate the median-median line [here](https://bgsu.instructure.com/courses/901773/pages/d7-median-median-line?module_item_id=6364145).  An R implementation of that is

```
median_median_line <- function(x, y, data)
{
  if(!missing(data))
  {
    x <- eval(substitute(x), data) 
    y <- eval(substitute(y), data) 
  }
  
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))

  #Step 1
  one_third_length <- floor(length(x) / 3)
  groups <- rep(1:3, times = switch((length(x) %% 3) + 1,
     one_third_length,
     c(one_third_length, one_third_length + 1, one_third_length),
     c(one_third_length + 1, one_third_length, one_third_length + 1)
  ))

  #Step 2
  x <- sort(x)
  y <- sort(y)
  
  #Step 3
  median_x <- tapply(x, groups, median)                                 
  median_y <- tapply(y, groups, median)

  #Step 4
  slope <- (median_y[3] - median_y[1]) / (median_x[3] - median_x[1])
  intercept <- median_y[1] - slope * median_x[1]

  #Step 5
  middle_prediction <- intercept + slope * median_x[2]
  intercept <- intercept + (median_y[2] - middle_prediction) / 3
  c(intercept = unname(intercept), slope = unname(slope))
}
```

To test it, here's an example:

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  time = c(.16, .24, .25, .30, .30, .32, .36, .36, .50, .50, .57, .61, .61, .68, .72, .72, .83, .88, .89),
  distance = c(12.1, 29.8, 32.7, 42.8, 44.2, 55.8, 63.5, 65.1, 124.6, 129.7, 150.2, 182.2, 189.4, 220.4, 250.4, 261.0, 334.5, 375.5, 399.1))
  
median_median_line(time, distance, dfr) 
#intercept     slope 
#   -113.6     520.0
```

Note the slightly odd way of specifying the groups.  The instructions are quite picky about how you define group sizes, so the more obvious method of `cut(x, quantile(x, seq.int(0, 1, 1/3)))` doesn't work.

Comment: Wow ! Thx a lot Richie Cotton !! It's perfect ;)

Comment: dfr <- data.frame(
  time = c(.16, .24, .25, .30, .30, .32, .36, .36, .50, .50, .57, .61, .61, .68, .72, .72, .83, .88, .89),
  distance = c(12.1, 29.8, 32.7, 42.8, 44.2, 55.8, 63.5, 65.1, 124.6, 129.7, 150.2, 182.2, 189.4, 220.4, 250.4, 261.0, 334.5, 375.5, 399.1));line(dfr); gives a different answer.

Comment: The link in the first line now seems broken.

Comment: I went through all the email discussion from 2017, [last message here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-May/074375.html). It seems that the code for the function `line()` has been updated since [Martin Mächler's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570867/10264278) answer. You can see `line`'s source code on [GitHub R source repo.](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/line.c). The function is still different from Richie Cotton's one so you might want to see both to make your mind on how to split your dataset in 3 balanced chunks.

Comment: The comments available with `?line` reflect these changes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but have you tried line() from the stats package?

From the helpfile:

**Value**

An object of class "tukeyline".

**References**

Tukey, J. W. (1977). Exploratory Data Analysis, Reading Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: Amended version of my original January 16 comment: A little experimenting with `line` on 9 data points suggests that this may not be the median-median line as normally given. In fact, if you let both x and y be 1:9 (all points lie on a line with slope 1), the line line has slope 1.2 ! While I originally thought perhaps the function implemented some other line than the Tukey resistant line (median-median line), I now suspect that it is intentded to be that line, and this is simply a bug in the `line` function.

Answer (score 2):

As member of the R Core team, I now have digged in the source code, and also studied the history of it.

Conclusion: The source C source code, added in 19961997, when R was still called alpha (and around version 0.14alpha)  already computed the quantiles not quite correctly... for some sample sizes.

More about this on the R mailing lists (not yet).